# How to LOOKUP second from last cell not equal to 0, and return header value

Tags: excel, lookup

The excel formula:

LOOKUP(2,1/(G698:AW698<>0),G3:AW3)

works perfectly in finding the last cell in a row that is not 0 and returning it's header value.

How do I apply the same theory to find the 2nd from last, and then 3rd from last value for non-zero cells?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to switch to INDEX/AGGREGATE

```
=INDEX($3:$3,AGGREGATE(14,6,COLUMN(G698:AW698)/((G698:AW698<>0)*(G698:AW698<>"")),2))
```

The `2` at the end is what returns the second to last.

Change the `2` at the end to `3` to get the third and so on.

Comment: Works perfect! Thanks. Can I ask what the 14,6 bit refers too?

Comment: see this on [AGGREGATE()](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43b9278e-6aa7-4f17-92b6-e19993fa26df?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1) it explains the formula better than I can.